# Bootstrap 3 - Are my breakpoints right? Site looks weird at width 780

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on this site:

http://stephaniebertha.com/indev/solartrak/

And I seem to be having a problem with breakpoints and general width responding to the layout. When you resize it and it starts to get down to 780 width, the layout breaks and it looks weird (the menu goes to a light gray color).

These are my media queries in custom.css (and in this order):

- max-width: 480px
- min-width: 481px
- min-width: 769px

Is this correct? Should I be doing them in this order? Any help you can throw my way would be helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reorganize your css thinking better the rules which ones you want for all devices sizes and which ones you don't

Example
in your custom.css you have this rule

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {

.navbar-default {
background: none;
border: 0 !important;
}

header.main {
height: 42px;
background: #f7941d;
}
```

the color of the nav bar shoul not be inside a @media rule thats why your nav get grey is smaller screens

and also read the documentation of the bootstrap grid it will help you a lot

Answer (score 0):

Breakpoints for Bootstrap 3 can be customized here:
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Under the headings 'Media queries breakpoints' and 'Layout and grid system'... It's a good idea to use a custom version so that you're choosing which files are relevant to you, and are compiling your own custom build of Bootstrap.

You can look inside your bootstrap.css file to find out where the breakpoints are set. If you use the same ones in your stylesheet the breaks should match up!

// Your link isn't live any more so I'm afraid I can't answer questions about that.